# How to use inline webfont in css?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I am using webfont in my website, sometimes font which i desired is not applied to text, In order to overcome that i want to load font while building CSSOM it self, so I tried this

```
body style="font-family: 'customfont'; src: url('XXXX/custom-font.woff2')"
```

I tried this also
    body style="font-family: 'customfont';

But of no use.

Comment: To use custom fonts you need to define fonts first in your CSS. `@font-face`

Comment: Why can't you use @font-face like any normal developer? It's your website, right?

Answer (score 0):

You should  use font-face inside style tag It might work and it's pretty fast and clean (Put it in head )

```
<style>
@font-face{
font-family:custom1;
src:url(XXX/fonts/XYZ.ttf);
}
</style>
```

then use  like  `style="font-family: 'custom1';

I hope It would be HelpFull

Answer (score 0):

```
  @font-face {
      font-family: myFont;
      src: url('XXXX/custom-font.woff2');
   }

   div {
      font-family: myFont;
   }
```

Try to @font-face Rule

Answer (score 0):

For inline use in HTML:

```
<style>
    @font-face{
        font-family: fontname;
        src: url(fontdirectory);
    }
</style>
```

Otherwise, put this in your CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: fontname;
    src: url(fontdirectory);
}
```

Then apply the font to the elements you want.